# Facebook Opengraph, Wordpress & NextGen Gallery

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph, nextgen-gallery

I have a facebook app.

On my Wordpress website, I have [NextGen Galleries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/) with a like button on each picture, it was working fine, until I moved servers.

Each time I clicked like, it liked the album and posted a link to facebook saying "Blah Blah liked an album on "Application Name".

It i no longer working like this.

I'm just wondering if anyone can help me with the open graph settings for my Application.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of [NextGen Galleries is 1.9.7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/). I glanced through the code and I don't see where it's generating any like buttons for gallery images. Was this feature added outside of NextGen galleries? By another plugin, perhaps?

**Edit:** I just noticed there are [multiple extensions](http://www.nextgen-gallery.com/nextgen-gallery-extension-plugins/) that support Facebook integration. Are you using one of them? If so, which one?